# 3-wayLight Switch Wiring (UK old to new colours)

Tags: wiring, uk

I am trying to replace a light switch from the old UK colours to the new. One of the light switches is 2 way, and the other 2 are simply on and off.

I have attached the photos. The old is the white cover, and the new is the charcoal coloured switch.

How do I map the old layout to the new? The labelling is rather confusing.

[image: old wiring]

[image: new wiring]

Comment: A simple internet search for "UK wiring colours" turned [this page](https://www.homehow.co.uk/blog/wiring-colours) up as the very first result. Since the hover text for the down vote arrow states, "This question does not show any research effort..." I've down voted.

Comment: @FreeMan - your link doesn't cover this scenario at all. In fact that would scare me to death & I'd call a sparky. It's not old colours, but it's not really new colours either. I have no clue [but I'm NOT a sparky] why it needs so many terminals. Even the intermediate switch in a [UK designation] 3-way only needs four terminals [plus a traveller], the 'ends' need only three. http://www.lightwiring.co.uk/three-way-light-switching-new-cable-colours/attachment/intermediate-switch-wiring-diagram-new-colours/ I see what they've done with the labelling, but it wouldn't make me any more confident

Comment: So what actually is the question here?

Comment: @SimonB - I thought it pretty obvious, but I've added it anyway.

Comment: @Tetsujin "It's not old colours, but it's not really new colours either." It's all old colours. These are the old 3-phase colours - red, yellow and blue. It's common to use a 3-phase cable for a UK 2-way switch (US: 3-way). The first phase colour is used for a single-phase connection. This also applies to the new wiring colours - brown and brown, black, grey. It seems the left-hand switch has been wired with a yellow conductor for the switched live which is unusual but acceptable.

Comment: @Tetsujin "I have no clue ... why it needs so many terminals." It's a 3 gang (rather than way) switch. That is, there are 3 independent switches in one unit here. There will be 3 rockers on the front of the unit. Each independent switch is a 2-way (US: 3-way) with 3 connections each for a total of 9 connections. The right-hand switch is wired for 2-way operation with all of L1, L2 and L3 in use. The left-hand and centre switches are used as 1-way (on/off) switches only so L3 is unused on both of these switches.

Comment: @GrahamNye - Thank you. That's why I'd have called a proper sparky :))

Answer (score 3):

> 3-wayLight Switch Wiring

You mean 3 gang, not 3 way.

> How do I map the old layout to the new?

The bottom row of the old switch maps to the top row of the new one and vice-versa.

It also looks like your new switch is metal and has an earth terminal, that terminal needs to be connected to the installation earth, there should be an earth terminal and/or wires in the backbox that you can connect it to with a short flylead.

> The labelling is rather confusing.

The first thing you need to know is that on UK multi-gang switches, the terminals for each switch nearly always form a triangle with two terminals at the top and one at the bottom or vice-versa. It's normal (but not universal) for the triangles of adjancent switches to be the opposite way up. You can usually figure out where the triangles are by counting the terminals.

Secondly, the switches that make up multi-gang switches are nearly always two-way switches*, even if they are being used as one-way switches. So you will commonly see unused terminals.

So on the old switch, the leftmost and rightmost switches have two terminals at the top and one terminal at the bottom. The middle switch has two terminals at the bottom and and one at the top.

The new switch is the other way up, the leftmost and rightmost switches have one terminal at the top and two at the bottom, while the middle switch has two terminals at the top and one at the bottom.

The other confusing thing is there are two ways to label the terminals of a two-way switch. Most switches are labeled with "com" for the common terminal and L1 and L2 for the other two terminals. However occasionally switches are labeled with L1 for the common terminal and L2 and L3 for the other two terminals.

```
regular  unusual
COM      L1
L1       L2
L2       L3
```

Your old switch follows the "unusual" labelling, your new switch follows the regular labeling but adds an extra digit to clarify which terminal belongs to which switch.

---

As for making sense of the wiring, the following is my best guess as to what is going on, but one would need to examine what is going on in the back box to be sure.

"Three and earth" cable in the UK is always manufacturered in the three phase colours (despite rarely if-ever being used for three-phase). So old three and earth is red yellow and blue (plus a bare earth), while new three and earth is brown black and grey (plus a bare earth).

The rightmost switch is the second switch of a two-way switching system and it's wiring is probablly unrelated to the other two and carried in a dedicated three and earth cable. The wire colours for two-way switching are pretty arbitrary there has never been a standard.

As for the left and centre switches, it looks like someone is using a three and earth cable to carry a neutral and two live conductors, either a permanent live and a switched live or two separate switched lives. When people did this, they usually used the blue wire for the neutral**, if only one of the lives was switched they would likely use the red as the permanent live and yellow as the switched live.

It looks like you have two red wires that are permanently live, and a red wire and a yellow wire that are switched lives. I suspect if you look in the back box you will find a bit of terminal block joining two black wires and a blue wire.

* For the Americans reading along, it's worth noting that light switch terminology is different in the US and the UK. What the brits call a one-way switch, the yanks call a two-way switch. What the brits call a two-way switch the yanks call a three-way switch and what the brits call an intermediate switch the yanks call a four-way switch.

** In the UK, Brown and Blue were used as the single phase colours in flexible cords decades before they were used in fixed wiring cable. So given a choice of yellow or blue for a neutral conductor most would pick blue. The situation now is more of a mess, some people map the old to new according to the three phase mapping and use grey for neutral, others remember black as the old neutral color and use it as the neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Each box contains three 2-way switches.

Looking at the pictures, and how they are wired, it looks like the "translation" from old to new is

```
L1 -> COMn
L2 -> Ln1
L3 -> Ln2
```

where 'n' is the (new) switch number, 1, 2 or 3.  Each switch has a "common" terminal at one end, and the position of the switch selects one of the two terminals at the other end.

The new switch terminals are upside down, when compared to the old one, so make sure you allow for that.  But in both cases, the middle switch is the opposite way up to the other two.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to replace a light switch from the old UK colours to the new.

Are you actually changing the wiring, or just the switch?

The new switch has the contacts swapped top to bottom compared to the old switch.

Going from left to right on the back of the switches, as pictured, the connections map like this:

Left

L1 -> COM1

L2 -> L11

L3 -> L12

Middle

L1 -> COM2

L2 -> L21

L3 -> L22

Right

L1 -> COM3

L2 -> L31

L3 -> L32

*Before* you disconnect the multiple red and yellow conductors label them so you connect them to the correct new locations. They are not interchangeable, even though they are the same colour.

You need to run a short earth wire from the brass terminal at the top left of the new switch to the earth terminal in the back box. You can use green/yellow insulated wire or bare wire with a green/yellow sleeve covering the length between the terminals. Supplies are available from DIY stores.